# How to access keys in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a numpy ndarray

```
{'type': 'message', 
 'subtype': 'channel_archive', 
 'channel_id': 'C1Q818VAR', 
 'channel_name': 'mindcloud', 
 'text': '<@U04JL900N> archived the channel', 
 'user': 'U04JL900N'}`.
```

I want to access the value associated with the `subtype` key and compare it with some string and if that holds true I want to print the value associated with the `text` key. How can I achieve this in python?

To make my question more clear: I wanted to check if my subtype is 'chat' and if so print out the value in the text key using for loop for all dictionary values. The one I posted above is just one row.

Comment: That is a dictionary, not a numpy array just do `d['type']` where `d` is the dictionary.

Comment: That's a dictionary, not a NumPy array. Please clarify and [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54347582/edit).

Answer (score 0):

You are using  {} braces this is for dictionary, generally in python the [] braces will use forarray.
So if you want to get values then use my_var[values].

Comment: How exactly do you make arrays with `()`…?

Comment: Sorry deceze I used tuples instead of array

Comment: `[]` is a *list* though. Might sound nitpicky, but a `list` is not a numpy array.

Comment: we can use [] braces like arr=np.array ([2,3,4,5], dtype =int).

Comment: Yeah, it's the `np.array()` that makes the numpy array, not the `[]`.

Comment: My intention is we can use array with [] like above my example

Comment: Guys sorry for the confusion I caused What I mean is that I wanted to access those dictionaries from list of dictionaries with value of 'subtype' = 'chat' and store the 'text' values in one csv file if that makes sense?